# RabbitMQ ест память

Tags: rabbitmq

Запущен сервер на `Python` с использованием `RabbitMQ`. Через некоторое время (около месяца) вот процесс съедает всю память и очереди останавливаются.
Вот этот процесс:

```
29431 rabbitmq  20   0 4330792 1,992g   4596 S  12,6 12,7 792:49.90 beam.smp
```

После убиства процесса все становится хорошо.

Судя по `beam.smp`, работает виртуальная машина erlang. Но почему она не освобождает память - непонятно.

Comment: Кол-во коннектов и открытых каналов проверили на момент, когда Rabbit сталкивается с критическим уровнем памяти?

Comment: Нет, но поедание памяти растет на глазах. Неделею назад значение `VIRT` было около 2000000, сейчас уже 4330792.

Comment: management UI подключен?

Comment: @Etki да, подключен

Comment: @faoxis в нем видны какие-нибудь аномалии, очереди с большим количеством непринятых сообщений, etc?

Comment: @Etki нет, все хорошо. Может ли быть такое, что обработанные сообщения не удаляются из оперативки и просто копятся ?

Comment: @faoxis в теории, конечно, да, но у меня нет компетенции такое говорить

Comment: Посмотрите через Managment UI, сколько коннектов, каналов, открытых файловых дескрипторов, открытых сокет дескрипторов, процессов, размер очередей. Может чего-то открыто слишком много?

Comment: Может приёмная сторона на успевает за передающей? И раббит не сбрасывает на диск мессаги, которые не могут быть доставлены немедленно?

Comment: Да я все проверил, ничего необычного. Никаких накопившихся очередей нет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Разобрался с вопросом. Дело было в том, что раббит написан на `erlang`. В прекрасном языке `erlang` сборщик мусора в виртуальной машине работает по старым и не особо эффективным алгоритмам. Он начинает чистить память только когда она заканчивается. Однако есть способы указать явно когда он запускается.

Таким образом, через настройки `RabbitMQ` можно достучаться до виртуальной машины `Erlang`. Для этого необходимо создать (если его нет) файл `/etc/rabbitmq/rabbitmq.config (Debian, Ubuntu)`. В нем можно указать процент от общей памяти или конкретное количество, сообщающее когда следует запускать сборщик мусора. Следует помнить, что учитывается не оперативная память, а виртуальная(!). Я сделал 20% от общей виртуальной памяти так:

```
[{rabbit, [{vm_memory_high_watermark, 0.2}]}].
```

Моя проблема заключалась в том, что значение по умолчанию 0.4, а это слишком много для нагруженного сервера в production...

Убедиться в том, что предел потребляемой виртуальной памяти не превышает норму можно командой `sudo rabbitmqctl status`. Нужный параметр: `vm_memory_limit`.